# printing sdk for IOS other than Airprint and google cloud print

Tags: ios

My requirement is print a webview content in iphone application. I don't want to use airprint or google cloud printing.Is there is any 3rd party sdk available for printing like "Hp mobile printing sdk" for windows mobile.

Thanks in advance
Srividya

Comment: any sdk availble for HP printer and Datamaxo'neil 4t/4te 4'mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is epson sdk for ios as well as android. You can check sdk [here](http://pos.epson.com/mobilesdks/index.htm)

Comment: any printing sdk availble for hp printers